# How can I see all my email activity & standard Salesforce tasks in one report/dashboard?

Tags: reporting, einstein-analytics, dashboard

Right now my org's email activity is being handled exclusively by Einstein Activity Capture, and all other activity (like calls, demos, meetings, SMS) is being saved as individual Tasks & Events in Salesforce.  Note that these Activity Capture emails are not stored as Salesforce task records, but [live outside of Salesforce altogether](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aac_limitations.htm&type=5):

> Activities added to Salesforce by Einstein Activity Capture are stored outside of Salesforce and don’t affect your Salesforce data allocations. There’s no additional costs for this storage.

I'd like to see the full view, per Sales rep, of their total emails, calls, meetings, demos, and calls for the month.

How do I create a single report/dashboard to see all these metrics in one place? Right now, I can only see Email metrics in Einstein Analytics and Demo/Call/Meeting/SMS metrics with standards Salesforce Reports and Dashboards

I haven't seen a way to adjust Analytics reports/dashboards to show the metrics I need, and it doesn't look like Activity Capture emails are visible to Salesforce Reports and Dashboards.

P.S. This is related to my previous post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271620/einstein-analytics-activity-type-picklist-values)

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no way yet... :'(

> Analytics
>   Because activities added to Salesforce with Einstein Activity Capture aren’t stored in Salesforce, they don’t show up in standard Salesforce reports. Use the Activities dashboard to see a summary of sales activities that were added to Salesforce manually and by Einstein Activity Capture. You can also use Activity Metrics to get a complete picture of your activities.

Read more on: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aac_limitations.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I actually opened the same case with Salesforce recently. So far my understanding is:
EAC has "Capture" and "Sync". Activities are Syncd which means they are stored in Salesforce as normal activity records. But email is only Captured from G-Suite or Outlook and stored in AWS, not in Salesforce.
So it is not possible.

The initial response was that we cannot get the data into SF from AWS, but I posted a followup case to SF and also posted a question on StackExchange here: [Einstein Activity Capture download email from AWS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/324375/einstein-activity-capture-download-email-from-aws)