# Einstein Activity Capture download email from AWS

Tags: email, einstein-analytics, einstein

In Einstein Activity Capture, email is "captured" and stored in AWS, not Salesforce. Is there any way to get the email from AWS into Salesforce? For example using Analytics REST API or Analytics External Data API from Apex? (I have Sales Cloud so may not even be able to use those APIs but.. need to know.)

Based on the Analytics External Data API it seems you can upload your own data and download it, but I cannot tell whether captured email is immediately mashed up and discarded or is does the original email still exist in AWS for 6 months.

The reason I want to know is that we upload email to Salesforce records. From what I can gather EAC displays the email from AWS in Lightning's Activity Timeline using an undisclosed internal API. But if the user sees that, then he will not attempt to upload email manually using the Outlook Integration side panel button. Then 6 months later, the email disappears from the timeline because it never really existed in Salesforce, it was in AWS.